# FlatCAM 8.994 Beta- Gerber copper layers not shown in Plot Area

Tags: pcb-fabrication, python

I am learning to CNC mill my first PCB. As project to learn it, I have chosen [the QuinLED V2.6 PCB](https://blog.quindorian.org/2016/08/esp8266-led-lighting-board-files-and-components-list.html/), which should have wide enough traces and pads to work as milled board hopefully.

This is what I see when open the contour, copper and drill layers:
[image: Only contour & drill layers are shown - no copper layers]

When I open the Gerber Editor, then there all the elements are shown:
[image: Gerber Editor]

Off course I tried the *Enable / Disable Plot* in the Project view. I can enable / disable the contour & drill layers, but the copper stay invisible.

I also have tried to switch from OpenGL (3D) to Legacy (2D) mode, but to no avail.

Anything else I could try?

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried on Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.10, Debian 11, all the same. Have you found a solution?
Last time I used Flatcam 8.994 about a year ago and it was working fine, seems like some updated dependency broke it.

Comment: @SergeyYatsuk no, for now I gave up on it. Couldn’t figure out, what’s the reason. Started to recreate the schematics but not the layout yet) in EasyEDA, but got sidetracked by more important stuff. If you figure out, what’s the reason, I am still interested. Could also be an issue/incompatibility between KiCAD and FlatCAM.  For completeness, I been on Mac OS Monterey. But don’t think the OS / Version is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip3 uninstall shapely
Found existing installation: shapely 2.0.1
Uninstalling shapely-2.0.1:
................
pip3 install shapely==1.7.0
```

That works for me.